# Sending PJlink commands with netcat

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tcp, netcat, windows-terminal

I have a projector that I want to control over TCP using a protocol called "PJlink", but I can't manage to get it working.  I'm currently trying to do this through Windows Terminal in WSL using `netcat`. I think I have managed to connect to the projector because when I use `nc <host> 4352` I get a response saying `PJLINK 0`.  This leads me to assume the connection is established.

But, when I send a command according to the specification of PJlink, I do not get any response. For example if I write `%1POWR ?` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I don't get any response.

According to the specification, all commands:

- start with a header containing a percentage character <kbd>%</kbd> ...
- followed by a character describing the class of the command ...
- followed by the command in upper case ...
- followed by a <kbd>Space</kbd> and arguments or a <kbd>?</kbd> and ...
- ended by a carriage return.

My suspicion is that I'm not sending a correct message, but rather that I'm sending UTF-8 or not sending a carriage return at the end.

Is there a way to check exactly what I'm sending? And to then to send what I want to send?

Comment: All chars in your example are same for UTF8 and ASCII, could be new line issue. Do you need ``\r\n`` or ``\n`` new line char? You can sniff your traffic with ``tcpdump`` or ``wireshark`` (which is easy to use GUI frontend to the same pcap lib)]

Comment: According to https://pjlink.jbmia.or.jp/english/data/5-1_PJLink_eng_20131210.pdf it is supposed do be ```CR``` which have code ```0d``` which rthen should be just ```\n```

Comment: Do you have another client, that works? You can sniff traffic and compare it with what you have.

Comment: Good find in the answer by GerardHPille, but I'm wondering based on what I read in that doc whether the projector could have a password?  In that case, you'd need to follow the authentication method, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test what you're sending with the PJLinkTEST4CNT.exe program from https://pjlink.jbmia.or.jp/english/dl_class2.html.

eg. this test python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python           # This is client.py file

import socket               # Import socket module

host = "192.168.1.44"
port = 4352

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM ) as s:
  s.connect((host, port))
  print (s.recv(1024))
  s.sendall(b'%1POWR ?\r')
  print (s.recv(1024))
  s.close()                     # Close the socket when done
```

gives the following output:

```
# python client.py
b'PJLINK 0\r'
b'%1POWR=1\r'
```

Typing commands into netcat is probably much too slow, if I read the PJLink protocol docs correctly.

Comment: Good find (and upvoted), but I am wondering what you see in the docs that make you think that it's timing out with manually entry?  The doc says the timeout is 30 seconds, right?

Comment: Sorry about that, memory isn't what it never has been. Got it here: https://projectorcontrol.blogspot.com/

Comment: Ah, no worries - Again, good find(s)!  That probably explains the OP problem, I hope.  Interested to hear if the Python script works for them.

Comment: I did try netcat and telnet. With telnet the test program hadto be killed. For the python script, I'd disabled authentication.

Comment: The python script works! Thanks